# adding new font in dompdf

Tags: fonts, dompdf

To add new font Arvo in DOMPdf I updated file dompdf_font_family_cache.dist
and added following code -

```
'arvo' => 
array (
  'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Arvo-Regular',
  'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Arvo-Bold',
  'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Arvo-Italic',
  'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Arvo-BoldItalic',
),
```

I included font files in lib/fonts directory
I added style sheet in html -

```
font-family: arvo;
```

But new font is not added in result pdf.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using ?

Comment: Instead of manually modifying dompdf_font_family_cache you should use load_font.php or (in dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3) the web-based installer located at www/fonts.php.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I used load_font.php and now fonts are working in output pdf.

Comment: how do i use load_font.php ? Means where to put my font name in above file ?

Comment: When i using web base installer then its asking about the user name and password in "dompdf_config.custom.inc.php" .

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I solved it:

1. Installing load_font.php from here: https://github.com/dompdf/utils/blob/master/load_font.php

   1.1. Create a new file in your root folder from your project and save.

   1.2. Next, run this line in your command line: `php load_font.php FONTNAME FONTPATH/fonts/EXAMPLEFONT.ttf`
2. Search and open the file dompdf_font_family_cache.php and update your file in this way (eg):

   ```
   'poppins' => 
   array(

   'normal' => $rootDir . '\lib\fonts\Poppins-Light_0',

   ),
   ```
3. Go to your PDF and use your font.

These few steps maybe solve the issue. :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. FYI I didn't need to do step 2 - the script did that automatically.

Comment: Hi ! this answered helped me but when I tried to generate my PDF it gave me an unpack error. The answer of jeliasson in that thread made the job for me, https://github.com/dompdf/php-font-lib/issues/47

Comment: nearly there, for me step 2 was non existent but I had to do the following:
1. lock dompdf to specific version
2. edit installed-fonts-dist.json in vendor folder and add:
    "autograf": {
        "normal": "Autograf",
        "bold": "Autograf",
        "italic": "Autograf",
        "bold_italic": "Autograf"
    },

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually modifying dompdf_font_family_cache you should use load_font.php or (in dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3) the web-based installer located at www/fonts.php.

Answer (score 1):

For windows with WAMP/XAMPP, etc...

1. Windows Command Prompt (Win+R-> cmd)
2. Go to C:\wamp\www\dompdf
3. Copy the desired font to that folder
4. Type (example)

C:\wamp\www\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe load_font_php Consola consola.ttf

Comment: I am using dompdf as part of a larger framework and was looking for a way to manually add a new font. your post gave me the idea to just take out dompdf and run the installer on that and then put the entire folder back in the folder. so thank you.