# DomPDF generation for chinese characters

Tags: php, dompdf, chinese-locale

I am trying to generate a PDF that will contain Chinese characters using dompdf.
Here is my code:

```
require('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
$html = ' <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
 <style>
     *{ font-family: DejaVu Sans, font-size: 12px;}
 </style> </head> <body>
 忠烈祠
  </body>
 </html>';
 $dompdf->load_html($html);
 $dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
 $filename = 'a.pdf';
$path = $filename;
file_put_contents($path, $output);
```

The problem is the the generated PDF show only squares when i open it with chrome or adobe reader, but it looks ok in Mozilla firefox.

Any sugestions?

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/79   refer second last answer... may help you..

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i went over all the answers i found on google. The problem with my project was the encoding on the text editor (netbeans at this point)

Answer (score 2):

First, move `def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);` above the require since the `def` function included with dompdf only defines the constant if it doesn't exist. When you include dompdf_config.inc.php that constant will be set at that time. Also, use `define` instead.

Second, you need a different font. The DejaVu fonts included with dompdf do not support CJK. For an overview read my answer to [Dompdf and set different font-family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517882/264628).

If you do not currently have a font you might try looking up [Firefly Sung](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-51316.html). Whatever font you decide to use it should be TTF in order for dompdf to use it.

Here's an example using Firefly Sung via the @font-face CSS rule, no installation required:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Firefly Sung';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/fonts/cjk/fireflysung.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
    * {
      font-family: Firefly Sung, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>忠烈祠</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried the above html with dompdf0.7 but still the characters as boxes. I am testing in ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0 with all the required extensions enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Suraj Dompdf does not include support all characters out of the box. Have you installed a font that supports your characters?

Comment: I am using exactly the same code above. I think it does not require any installation as the font src url is external. Please advice.

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` set to true?

Comment: Yes allow_url_fopen is set to true. It seems to work now. But when I tried with japanese characters there are still boxes for few characters. I think the font included in src does not support all japanese characters. Also the pdf size is too large 15.7mb. Please check the html here http://54.153.85.27/testhtml1.html. The pdf generated url is http://54.153.85.27/document_test.pdf. Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify a separate font file for each weight. I don't have a bold version of that font, but if you duplicate the `@font-face` declaration but change the weight to bold you will at least see the characters. As for PDF size, enable font subsetting.

Comment: this answer does not work for me,  PDF show only squares