# Chinese characters do not appear in codeigniter dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I made a pdf with dompdf on the codeigniter when xampp was able to appear but when uploaded to the server it didn't appear and the checkbox didn't appear

Why?
Can you help me?

CSS :

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Firefly';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url('<?php echo base_url() ?>/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/fireflysung.ttf') format('truetype');
      }

      body{
        font-family: 'Firefly';
      }
```

My html checkbox :

```
<?php $br=0; foreach ($purchase as $a): $br++;?>
           <?php $wik=$br%2; if ( $wik == 1): ?>
              <tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <td>
                      <label><input type="checkbox" <?php if ($data->id_purchase==$a->id_purchase): ?>
                        checked
                        <?php else: ?>
                          disabled
                      <?php endif; ?>> <?php echo $a->nama ?> </label>
                    </td>
          <?php $wik2=$br%2; if ($wik2 == 0): ?>
             </tr>
          <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

pdf in xampp
[image: pdf in xampp]

pdf in server
[image: pdf in server]

Comment: Is your live server running Linux?

Comment: right, my  live server  is linux

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive, check if your font src is loaded correctly, check for any errors in your console.

Comment: I have checked and everything is correct, but it doesn't appear. and why the checkbox didn't appear too?

Comment: Show us the code of the checkbox ( :

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @Arifhidayah I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435198/dompdf-generation-for-chinese-characters) helps