# domPDF create an empty PDF with custom font

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf

I using domPDF and I' trying to add a custom font (neosans).

I use `dompdf/www/fonts.php` to add my font into domPDF. `.ufm` and `.ttf` files were created. I used a online convert to create `.afm` file and I put it in the fonts folder.

The font name is added into `dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php` and `dompdf_font_family_cache.php`.

In CSS (`<style>` tag in the document) I set :

> font-family: neosans;

but when I display the PDF the font is blank.

If I set Arial it's ok.

Comment: Still having issues? You don't need the .AFM file unless you're document is encoded with Windows ANSI, which is *not* recommended. Also, the font should be automatically added to `dompdf_font_family_cache.php`, you shouldn't have to do anything manually.

Comment: The following may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24517882/264628

Comment: Yes I tried command line without success... For the moment I put this issue on the side and I have tested wkhtmltopdf that have better output.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf and PhantomJS are both better options if you can implement them since they use a headless version of Safari.