# Laravel DomPdf Add Custom Font

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am trying to use OLD English font in Dompdf with Laravel.,
I have inserted the font in laravel view. But it seems when generating the pdf It is not working.I tried editing `dompdf >vendor >.../dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php` File.But no luck,

Can anyone Suggest a Solution?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family) does this help!

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor.
No it doent help

Comment: You shouldn't edit that file directly. The most straightforward method is to use an `@font-face` declaration. You indicated in comments that you already tried this...you should update your question so we can see _what_ you tried. Does the running process have read/write access to the storage/fonts directory as is the default for laravel-dompdf ([ref](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#configuration))?

Answer (score 34):

1. Make a fonts directory in the storage folder of your Laravel project. ( storage/fonts )
2. Put your .otf or .ttf files in the storage/fonts directory.
3. In your view/html add @font-face rules by using the storage_path method Laravel provides.

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Your custom font name';
       src: url({{ storage_path('fonts\your-custom-font.ttf') }}) format("truetype");
       font-weight: 400; // use the matching font-weight here ( 100, 200, 300, 400, etc).
       font-style: normal; // use the matching font-style here
   }
   ```
4. Add font-family rules to your css as seen below

   ```
   body {
       font-family: "Your custom font name";
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me, from some reason, it doesn't work. I checked and the font file exists.

Comment: Is it a .ttf file?

Comment: Yes, it is a .ttf file.

Comment: Do you have a github repo I can check?

Comment: No, but I opened a new issue with the entire info - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58132528/1039488

Comment: It worked great for me. I'd just add:
- put @font-face before any other CSS statement
- php process must be able to write on storage/fonts

Comment: This works, but I also had to define the `chroot` option for domPDF for it to work: `$options->set('chroot', storage_path());`

Comment: If you use GIT, you should also check in the storag/fonts folder (but not the files) e.g. add a .gitignore file with folowing content: 
`*` (newline)
`!.gitignore`

Comment: Also make sure your custom `font-family` doesn't contain spaces or it might not work for some reason

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to include custom fonts too. 
I included the font in the view (using @font-face declaration), but when I tried to generate the pdf, it gave me an ErrorException in AdobeFontMetrics.php.
I resolved by creating a fonts folder in the storage folder of your laravel project.
So now I have:

```
> storage
    > app
    > fonts
    > framework
    > logs
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

Place the font in the `storage/fonts` folder.

In my example OpenSans is in `storage/fonts/`

Open sans can also be downloaded from [GoogleFonts](https://fonts.google.com/share?selection.family=Open%20Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800).

then add the following style tag to your html.

```
<style>
          
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 700;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 700;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 800;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 800;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 300;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 300;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-Medium.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 500;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-MediumItalic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 500;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 400;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 600;
                font-style: normal;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 600;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                src: url({{ storage_path("fonts/static/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf") }}) format("truetype");
                font-weight: 400;
                font-style: italic;
            }
    
            body {
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Journal';
src: url('yourwebsite.com/journal.ttf")}}') format('truetype');
}
.typed {
font-family: 'Journal';
}
<p class='typed'>Signature</p>
```

Make sure to put your font name like this  **font: Journal**; It will work.

Plus add fonts folder under your storage folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set font into html page which is load in Dompdf
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Helvetica';
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        src: url("font url");
      }
      body {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>hello world</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is anyone found an answer !

Comment: Not Working.Thanks

Comment: oic you have a solution ... for everyone's benefit you should add an answer indicating how you resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank You @BrianS
No,I do not have a solution.Although I have found a alternative solution(Not related to Laravel).
I have created a printed layout which default heading and tables of the bill which printed to the paper,
And used css styling and spaces in dompdf to keep things things in order,rather than printing all once.
:D

Comment: anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem but I resolved that by a single-line code.
If you got to the definition of Dompdf if provide to `setOption` method to use.

The code needs to update in your controller

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('promo-template.pdf', compact('data'))
            ->setOption('fontDir', public_path('/fonts'));
```

It will generate an installed-fonts.json file in font dir.
[image]

In your style.css include your font face it will automatically get the custom font and will make a JSON file for that.