# Laravel add add font in dompdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, fonts, dompdf

Please, give me answer, how i can add external font in dompdf load view :) 
This is my structure `

Fonts folder exists in storage/fonts/ and fonts are exists in 
vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/
And this is my code `

This is my controller

```
public function generatePdf($data)
{
    $data = Profile::find($data);

    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->setOptions(['fontDir' => storage_path('fonts/'), 'defaultFont' => 
    'OpenSansCondensedBold, OpenSans']);

    if ($data->graph_type == 'vertical') {
        $pdf->loadView('pdf.view', compact('data'));
    } else {
        $pdf->loadView('pdf.view', compact('data'))->setPaper('a4', 
        'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->output();
    }
    return $pdf->download();
}
```

View `
text in   tag is my css code for pdf view 
and text in  tag is my html tag

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        h3{
            //font-family: "OpenSansCondensedBold";
            color: #7c5337;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 18px;
            margin: 30px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        span{
            //font-family: "OpenSans";
            color: #484444;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 14px;
            margin: 14px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        h2{
            //font-family: "OpenSans";
            color: #484444;
            font-size: 30px;
            line-height: 21px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        small{
            color: #7c5337;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0 0 5px 0;
        }

        .left-block{
            float: left;
            padding-top: 200px;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        .left-block .image-block img{
            max-width: 173px;
            max-height: 526px;
        }
        .right-block {
            float: right;
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 6%;
        }


        .topSection{
            width:80%;
            margin:  0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .info-block {
            padding:30px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #775035;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: 560px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .tiknesWidth li{
            color: #775035;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left-block">
        <div class="image-block">
            <?php if (is_null($data->file_pdf) || empty($data->file_pdf)) { 
            ?>
                <img class="ak-image-responsive" src="
                {{url('/user/images/not-image.png')}}">
            <?php } else { ?>
                <img class="ak-image-responsive" src="
                {{asset('/storage/product/pdf/'.$data->file_pdf)}}" >
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-block">
        <div class="topSection">
            <img src="{{url('/user/images/site-logo.png')}}"><br><br><br>
            <div class="text-block">
                <small>9407 Brown Lane #2</small><br>
                <small>Austin, Texas 78754</small><br>
                <small>P: 512-836-8990 office</small><br>
                <small>F: 512-836-9796 fax</small><br>
                <small>sales.office@finelumber.com</small><br>
                <small>www.finelumber.com</small><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-block">
            <h3>PROFILE NAME</h3>
            <h2>{{$data->profile_name}}</h2>
            <ul class="tiknesWidth">
                <li style="margin-left: -40px;">
                    <h3>THICKNESS</h3>
                    <span style="margin-left: -40px;">{{(($data-
                    >dimensions_first > 0) ? $data->dimensions_first : '' ) 
                    . (($data->dimensions_first == 0 || $data-
                    >dimensions_sub_first == 0) ? '' : '-') . (($data-
                    >dimensions_sub_first > 0 ) ? $data-
                      >dimensions_sub_first : '')}}</span>
                </li>
                <li style="margin-left: 50px;">
                    <h3>WIDTH</h3>
                    <span>{{(($data->dimensions_second > 0) ? $data-
                    >dimensions_second : '') .(($data->dimensions_second == 
                    0 || $data->dimensions_sub_second == 0) ? '' : '-'). 
                    (($data->dimensions_sub_second > 0) ? $data-
                    >dimensions_sub_second : '')}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h3>SPECIES IN STOCK</h3>
            <span>
                    @if ($data->stock)
                    @foreach($data->stock as $key => $stock)
                        @if (count($data->stock) == $key + 1)
                            {{$stock->name}}
                        @else
                            {{$stock->name.','}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </span>
            <h3>CATEGORY</h3>
            <span>{{$data->category->name}}</span>
            <h3>Fine Lumber ID</h3>
            <span>{{$data->lumber_id}}</span>
            <h3>Fine Lumber Location</h3>
            <span>{{$data->lumber_location}}</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dompdf and set different font-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family)

Comment: The process for adding fonts to Dompdf isn't generally specific to the installation. So long as you Laravel configuration is ok (and it looks like it is) you should be able to use the recommended method of referencing the font in your CSS.

Comment: Here's something more specific to Laravel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636379/laravel-dompdf-add-custom-font