# How to make fonts in DOMPDF library

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using the "DOMPDF" library with Laravel to create a PDF. It needs to be in Arabic with a font of dejavu sans mono or dejavu sans.
But, I have trouble with the fonts Times-Roman and Helvetica.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
* { font-family:"times-roman" ,normal; }
</style>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: there are already questions about this on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family you may have to load the font

Comment: thank you.. but  please how to get root folder of my project to place  (load_font.php)

Comment: I think you have to put it in the public folder according to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure but i dont know, never used laravel.