# How to load font-family in dompdf using laravel library?

Tags: php, html

I need to implement card convert the html and php into pdf. This card section have different fonts. I'm using google fonts for card.

but no any changes in pdf

code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('downloadflyerpreview');
$pdf->setOptions(['dpi'=>300,'isHtml5ParserEnabled', true,'isRemoteEnabled' => true,'defaultMediaType'=>'all','isFontSubsettingEnabled'=> true,'defaultFont' => '']);
$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
return $pdf->download('flyerpreview.pdf');
return view('downloadflyerpreview',compact('goto'));
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dompdf and set different font-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family)