# Dompdf set tamil font supported font-family

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I have been trying to set tamil font to display in PDF by using dompdf in codeigniter. As followed this instruction [Dompdf and set different font-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family) I have set the font family but this is not working for tamil fonts. I have updated Baamini.ttf inside the lip folder and I have set the font family as like below,

```
@font-face {
            font-family: "Baamini";           
            src: url(\'fonts/Baamini.ttf\') format("truetype");
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;

        } 
        
         body{
            font-family: "Baamini";            
        }
```

In my controller file

```
$this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $html = $this->load->view('ret_purchase/vendor_ack', $data,true);
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper('A4', "portriat" );
       
        $dompdf->render();
         $file = $dompdf->output();
        $dompdf->stream("VendorAck.pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
```

but when I create pdf it's showing like square brackets instead of tamil fonts.

Comment: `url(\'fonts/Baamini.ttf\')` seems odd to me, try `url("/fonts/Baamini.ttf")`

Comment: I have tried this but same result yet, not showing the tamil fonts

Comment: Try to use unicode and font family like `font-family: "freeserif"`